# "string indices must be integers" error when scraping json in Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to grab some data from a website. The url is

```
https://rbx.rocks/apis/item?id=1285307
```

So right now i got

```
print requests.get('https://rbx.rocks/apis/item?id=1285307').json()[0]['stats']
```

If ran, it gives the error, "string indices must be integers"

I'm currently running python 2.7

Comment: try removing `[0]`

Comment: Still gives the same error.

Comment: print the result of `requests.get('https://rbx.rocks/apis/item?id=1285307').json()[0]`

Comment: That prints just "{"

Comment: That's the problem. You are trying to index the string "{" using the index "stats" and, obviously, is a non-sense. When you do `[0]` you are getting the first character in the json (`{`). You need do just `.json()` (without `[0]`), and then parse that json somewhat.

Comment: Well, I get the same error when I just do print 
        `requests.get('https://rbx.rocks/apis/item?id=1285307').json()['stats']`

Comment: Yes, you need to parse the json before index it

Comment: what is the source of the code you supplied? and what is your objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON object.

add json.loads() as:

```
import requests
import json

print json.loads(requests.get('https://rbx.rocks/apis/item?id=1285307').json())['stats']
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought of doing json.loads but when I did that I made it `print json.loads(requests.get('https://rbx.rocks/apis/item?id=1285307').json()['stats'])`

Comment: I see. You can print individually each step as @sancho bellow suggested to avoid such problems in the future.

Comment: I've never thought of that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the source of error, you could perform "one operation at a time", and get details on the result, e.g.

```
a = requests.get('https://rbx.rocks/apis/item?id=1285307')
print(a, type(a))
b = a.json()
print(b, type(b))
c = b[0]
print(c, type(c))
d = c['stats']
print(d, type(d))
```

This is clearly not the solution, but:

1. It may help.
2. It does not fit in a comment.